# How do you find the matrix before elementary row operations have been applied?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

The following row operations are applied (in order) to a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$:
$\space R2\rightarrow R2 - R1,\; R3 \rightarrow R3 - 4R1, \;R3 \rightarrow R3 - 2R2$.

The matrix which results is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Solve the system of equations $Ax=
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
-1\\
2 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$

For the question above, I was wondering how I could find the original matrix $A$ to be able to then solve the system of equations? How do I "work backwards" with the given elementary row operations? How do I even show my working in terms of proper notation?

Comment: You apply the opposite of each operation, being sure to start with reversing the last one, then the second last, etc.

Comment: Aren't the solutions the same as for your matrix obtained?

Answer (score 0):

Every step you describe can be reversed. Note that I will use the notation $R_i^{(n)}$ for the *new* $i$-th row (i.e., after the operation is applied) and $R_i^{(o)}$ for the *old* $i$-th row (before the operation).

Let us look at the example $R3\to R3-2R2$. In that case, you have

$$\begin{align}
R_2^{(n)} &= R_2^{(o)}
R_3^{(n)} &= R_3^{(o)} - 2\cdot R_2^{(o)}\\
\end{align}
$$

It is relatively simple to see that this also means that you have

$$
\begin{align}
R_2^{(o)} &= R_2^{(n)}
R_3^{(o)} &= R_3^{(n)} + 2\cdot R_2^{(o)} = R_3^{(n)} + 2\cdot R_2^{(n)}
\end{align}
$$

which means that the reverse of the operation $$R_3\to R_3 - 2R_2$$ is the operation $$R_3 \to R_3 + 2R_2.$$

Comment: I see, so would all of the elementary Row operations (applied in order) be: $R3 \rightarrow R3 + 2R2, \; R3 \rightarrow R3 + 4R1, \; R2 \rightarrow R2 + R1$?

The answer would then be $$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 3 & 4 \\
4 & 10 & 14 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @JasonXu Did you try it out for yourself? Did you apply the original order of operations to your answer, and get the correct matrix out?

Answer (score 0):

You apply the same operations by the same order to$$\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix}.$$You will get\begin{align}\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix}&\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}2\\-3\\2\end{bmatrix}\\&\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}2\\-3\\-6\end{bmatrix}\\&\rightarrow\begin{bmatrix}2\\-3\\0\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}And now you solve the system$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}x=\begin{bmatrix}2\\-3\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$